# After completion of Ubuntu installation using live USB I restart & remove the flash drive then computer boots into Windows 10 and no sign of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, hp, usb-installation, rufus

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a dual boot scenario with Windows 10.
The installation goes through everytime without any errors or issue. Upon completion I am prompted to restart and after I am asked to remove the flash drive I do and hit enter but the laptop immediately reboots into Windows 10 with no sign of Ubuntu being installed. In fact I check the disk management and the partition that I set to install Ubuntu on (using custom partitioning choosing the something else option in the Ubuntu installer) is still unallocated and the EFI partition has no new folder related to Grub or Ubuntu. BIOS environment also doesn't have any new entry.

I should list the steps that I have already taken to troubleshoot this.

1. I have unchecked fast boot option in control panel and disabled hibernation via powershell command *powercfg /h off*
2. I have checked the installation media to have GPT scheme (the same as computer's internal disk) and to boot in UEFI mode (the only option available).
3. I have used powershell repair command *chkdsk /f /r* on EFI partition to resolve my previous issue with Grub installation failing mid installation which is no longer a problem.

Comment: Did you go into your BIOS settings and make sure that your first boot priority has the volume where you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: You mean right before letting windows 10 to boot automatically after installation is complete? I have tried looking into BIOS setting after I see nothing has changed but I don't see the volume where I installed Ubuntu because it's like installation never happened and the partition still appears unallocated in windows like how I originally prepared it for installation.

Comment: Windows does not know about Linux partitions, so it will not show it. If you want to see details use live installer and run this report: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: That's correct Windows by default cannot read ext4 but even after installation if I enter live media environment and hit try Ubuntu I would see the entire hard drive without any partitions in the GNOME disks application whereas before installation I could see all windows partitions and the free space where I had prepared to install Ubuntu on. Also if I recreate my live media inside Windows with Rufus next time I enter live usb I would see the Ubuntu partition is free space again.

Comment: Don't use Windows to prepare partitions for Ubuntu. You can use "Disks" in the live session.  You will want to make unpartitioned free space (don't create a partition or file system).  Is there a reason why you will not use `boot-repair`? If you actually installed Ubuntu, that should resolve the problem. In any case, the boot repair summary will give helpful diagnostic information. Before responding, please make sure that you have thoroughly tried all suggestions and provided all requested information.

Comment: Actually I don't think it has to do with windows itself I think the culprit may be the intel hard drive. If I return to live usb after Ubuntu installation & restart the hard drive is shown in GNOME disks application as Intel RSTe RAID Member (1.4.01). I read in Ubuntu documentations that it should be disabled like fastboot but I am not sure if that would break windows or not also I tried unchecking third party software installation this time (because I read shim may be buggy with enrolling MOKs) and this time I can see the ubuntu option in BIOS setting but still that boots into windows

Comment: Here is the report. The sda is my live usb and nvme0n1 is my internal hard disk and nvme1n1 is the intel optane https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fKjRyfCZmh/